# SQLite ORDER BY clause not working

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a database containing the fields, username, password, scores, kills, and time. I'm trying to order all the records within by score in ascending order, so the highest score is at the top.

The function I have made to do this runs fine, and produces no errors, but doesn't change the order in any way.

Am I doing something wrong? All help appreciated.

The function:

```
# Orders database by high score
def order_db():
    """
    Orders the database rows,
    so first row has highest
    score.
    """
    open_db()
    command = ("""
                SELECT * FROM players
                ORDER BY score ASC
                """)
    cur.execute(command)
    close_db()
```

Full code:
http://pastebin.com/Bw14dTaa

I have tried changing the function in different ways, using:

```
cur.executemany(command)
```

Or changing the format of the SQLite statement:

```
("""
SELECT * FROM players
ORDER BY score ASC;
 """)
```

EDIT:

So my display_db() function was messing up and not showing them ordered. I fixed this by moving the order_db() function inside of it after the select statement is executed. Moving it above seems to break it again and I'm confused as to why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is fine. However given what you want to do, you need to sort in decreasing order, not ascending:

```
command = ("""SELECT * FROM players
              ORDER BY score DESC
           """)
```

Sql consider the beginning to be the top, that's why you need DESC if you want the highest to be at the top.

I suppose there is no change in ordering when you use ASC because the data is already sorted in ascending order.

Comment: Thanks, the documentation page shows it the wrong way for some reason. Still having issues in that what is printed out never changes but I believe that is something wrong with my function to display it.